# Cannot upgrade Mac OSX because my hard drive is encrypted

Tags: macos, upgrade, monterey

I wanted to upgrade from Big Sur to Monterey and after the download completed, I get this message, that I cannot upgrade because my disk was encrypted.

[image]

Comment: How did you encrypt this disk in the first place? If you're already logged in as the admin user, then the disk should be unlocked.

Comment: While installing Mac OSX a year ago approx. 

The disk is the first thing I have to unlock while booting any further to the login screen, so both should be unlocked by now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working in the end! Coming from another bug I got the following solution steps, in order to get it working.

[image: Warning in FileVault]

As you can see here in FileVault, there was a warning displayed, that were some users not being able to unlock the disk.
The button **"Enable users..."** in addition to the button **"Turn Off FileVault"** were not clickable, so I troubeshooted that problem with [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335883/cannot-enable-filevault-on-macos-high-sierra) and came to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/74scld/unable_to_turn_on_filevault_on_high_sierra_apfs/do1cee2/). The [second](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340976/266852) answer from the first post was also needed to troubleshoot and fix the bug.

**Short summary / tl;dr**

1. Identify if your current or any user has Secure Token enabled with

   `sudo sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus <usr>`
2. Check every user on your system

- 2.1 Search for users

  `dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_'`
- 2.2 Check the user with

  `sudo sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus <user>`

3. If for every user the return is
   `Secure token is DISABLED for user <user>`

   `sudo rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

   for reenabling the Apple Setup Page

   and **reboot normally**

- 3.1 Setup a new user in the setup menu

  This user will have the Secure Token ENABLED
- 3.2 Go to Users & Groups and reset the other account's password

  The old user will now have his Secure Token ENABLED (again / reenabled)
- 3.3 Log out with the current (temporary) user
- 3.4 Log in with the old user

4. Check the update page again and update to Monterey
   The error should be gone[image: gone]

Comment: Thank you so much this was 100% the solution I needed. I had set up FileVault when I originally installed MacOS a few versions before Monterey. After setting up the secondary Admin account I was able to reset the password for the original account and install without issues after that without having to disable FileVault.

Answer (score 2):

Same here,
as interim solution i would try

- booting into rescue mode,
- deactivate DISK AES Encryption
- normal boot and install
- back to recovery and reactivate AES Encryption

Comment: Sounds like a dirty hack, but will do so if there is no other way. Thanks

Comment: I don’t believe it is possible to use Disk Utility to remove encryption from a drive (in-place) when the entire disk is encrypted with a disk password  (as opposed to the more commonplace user-level filevault situation). (Maybe with an external drive as an interim store for the disk contents, but not in one step and not without extra storage devices.)